# Terminate program with closing all resources

Tags: multithreading, sockets

I have a program, which starts internally several threads and manages server and client sockets.

Is it necessary to close all sockets explicitly before program termination (in shutdown hook) and also interrupt all child processes?

Comment: Regarding the use of shutdown hook, I think the consideration is that if you have something needs to persist in the duration of shutdown, or something additional actions you want the program to ensure/perform in the duration of shutdown, then it worth to consider; otherwise, when the program end, the socket will be released

Answer (score 1):

When you call `System.exit()`, or maybe use some other tool that does a `kill the-jvm-pid`, then that will end all activity immediately. Sockets will be closed and all that. So, technically, you should get to "all things closed" automatically.

But: ask yourself if that is **really** what you want.

In most *real world* applications, **orderly shutdown** is just as important as *orderly startup*. You don't just walk into your computing center and rip power plugs from power outlets.

Meaning: instead of just "killing" your application, consider if it makes sense that this service has a "shutdown" feature that you can invoke, so that ongoing activities are ended in *meaningful* ways. That isn't required for all kinds of applications, it really depends on context though.